# Why is Django template engine adding myapp/myview to my URLs?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I made a template to list documents with a download link, but instead of linking to :

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/mydoc.csv

it links to :

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/myview/media/mydoc.csv

**In myapp/templates/myapp/list.html**

```
    <ul>
    {% for document in documents %}
        <li><a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.docfile.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

document.docfile.url does actually links to media/mydoc.csv so that I guess it has to do with the template engine.

**Versions**

- Python : 3.7.2
- Django : 2.1.7
- OS : Windows 10

**In myapp/models.py**

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
```

**In myapp/views.py**

```
def myview(request):

    documents = Document.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'myapp/list.html', {'documents': documents})
```

**In myapp/urls.py**

```
app_name = 'myapp'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('myview/', views.myview, name='myview'),
]
```

**In myproject/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**In settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

Since it is my fist Django app (and first webapp ever) I guess I missed something very basic. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: No, it is a result of setting a `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MEDIA_URL is wrong. You missed the starting slash.

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Thanks, it corrected the error. As an addition with this setting the file is now pointing to media/mydoc.cvs while the models says media/documents/mydoc.csv. However it is probably another story...